# Using assertArrayEquals in unit tests

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

My intention is to use `assertArrayEquals(int[], int[])` JUnit method described in [the API](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) for verification of one method in my class.

But Eclipse shows me the error message that it can't recognize such a method. Those two imports are in place:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: What version of JUnit you're using? Have you used JUnit assertions before? Are you sure you want unit testing and not e.g. `java.util.Arrays.equals/deepEquals` methods?

Comment: Frankly I don't know what version of JUnit I'm using, but I know I've downloaded the Eclipse Version: 3.5.1 and JUnit was included. I haven't been using JUnit assertions before, I'm just learning. And yeah, I want unit testing.

Comment: Yes, and the referenced JavaDoc is for JUnit 4. Javadoc for 3.8.1 can be found [here](http://www.junit.org/junit/javadoc/3.8.1/index.html)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This would work with **JUnit 5**:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1,2,3},new int[]{1,2,3});
```

This should work with **JUnit 4**:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
 
public class JUnitTest {
 
    /** Have JUnit run this test() method. */
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
 
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1,2,3},new int[]{1,2,3});
 
    }
}
```

---

This is the same for the old JUnit framework (**JUnit 3**):

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class JUnitTest extends TestCase {
  public void test() {
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1,2,3},new int[]{1,2,3});
  }
}
```

Note the difference: no Annotations and the test class is a subclass of TestCase (which implements the static assert methods).

Comment: It is JUnit3, but I'm getting the message: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method assertArrayEquals(int[], int[]) is undefined for the type DeckTest

Comment: are you extending TestCase? Please post sample code that shows the class in question.

Comment: @AndoidNoob - Assert@assertArrayEquals has been introduced with JUnit 4. So you either have to switch to JUnit 4 (always recommended) or verify the equality of arrays with several Java statements (loop through the array after making sure, they're of the same size)

Comment: @Andreas_D your answer implies that `assertArrayEquals` can be used with JUnit 3. It is in contradiction with your own comment and with siik's tests (as well as my tests). `assertArrayEquals` is simply incompatible with JUnit 3.

Answer (score 30):

This could be useful if you want to use just assertEquals without depending on your Junit version

```
assertTrue(Arrays.equals(expected, actual));
```

Comment: However, the fail message for this will only be something like "expected true, was false". `assertArrayEquals` creates a message which describes why the arrays are not equal, e.g. different length or index at which they contain different elements.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

`assertArrayEquals` is a static method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing JUnit 3.x style tests which extend [TestCase](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/index.html?org/junit/Assert.html), then you don't need to use the `Assert` qualifier - TestCase extends Assert itself and so these methods are available without the qualifier.

If you use JUnit 4 annotations, avoiding the TestCase base class, then the `Assert` qualifier is needed, as well as the import `org.junit.Assert`. You can use a static import to avoid the qualifier in these cases, but these are considered [poor style](http://www.symphonious.net/2004/02/06/static-imports-are-evil/) by some.