# Comparing two object arrays in JUnit

Tags: java, arrays, junit, tdd

I have implemented a cardgame and need to test the shuffle method. I am using netbeans 7.2 and am now having a problem because the deckBeforeShuffle is empty after i call the instance.shuffleDeck method so I cant compare it with my deckAfterShuffle array to see if it is shuffled! Its the first time I am using JUnit and have tried different ways to fix this but it has all been in vain.

```
@Test
public void testShuffleDeck() {
    System.out.println("shuffleDeck");
    CardDeck instance = new CardDeck(1);
    ArrayList<Card> deckBeforeShuffle = instance.getDeck();         
    instance.shuffleDeck();        
    ArrayList<Card> deckAfterShuffle = instance.getDeck();        
    boolean isShuffled = false;
    int position = 0;
    System.out.println(deckBeforeShuffle.size());
    while(position<deckBeforeShuffle.size() && !isShuffled){

        if(deckBeforeShuffle.get(position).getSuitValue() != deckAfterShuffle.get(position).getSuitValue() && deckBeforeShuffle.get(position).getvalue() != deckAfterShuffle.get(position).getvalue()){

        isShuffled = true;

        }
        position++;
    }
    assertEquals(true, isShuffled); 
}
```

My shuffle method!

public void shuffleDeck(){

```
    ArrayList<Card> temp = new ArrayList();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int position;
    while(deck.size() > 0){

        position = rand.nextInt(deck.size());
        temp.add(deck.remove(position));
    }
    deck = temp;
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

actually it would suffice to to check for non-equality. the List's [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method will take care of the rest.

```
assertFalse(deckBeforeShuffle.equals(deckAfterShuffle)); // not equal
assertEquals(deckBeforeShuffle.size(), deckAfterShuffle.size()); // but same size
assertEquals( // and same number of elements
    new HashSet<Card>(deckBeforeShuffle), new HashSet<Card>(deckAfterShuffle);
```

And for the shuffling, you can use the existing [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method. Beware, however that you have to make a copy of the list before shuffling it.

Comment: in addition you can itterate over the `deckBeforeShuffle` and check if each element is in the `deckAfterShuffle` List

Comment: @Fusselchen yes, but I thought that to be paranoid, after all, if the size is right and the order is wrong, what other elements will there be? But I have a new idea...

Comment: deckBeforeShuffle is always empty after I call the instance.shuffleDeck method. I am using JUnit 4 if that information is of any help. I have never written tests before and am confused to why it gets emptied after instance.shuffleDeck method is called

Comment: @Zok well then your shuffleDeck method is wrong. add it to you question and we might be able to find the error

Comment: I have added my shuffleDeck method. But it look like it works when I print the deck array

Comment: @Zok what do you expect on calling `deck.remove(position)`? ..... it removes the element from the first deck...

Comment: @Fusselchen it is suppose to remove the element from the first deck and add it to temp because deck.size() should be reduced by 1 so I can draw a new random number and remove another element from deck and add it to temp until there are no elements left in deck. After the while loop I am copying all elements from temp back to deck and it is randomly sorted. Sorry if my explanation is bad!

Comment: you do not copy back, you replace the reference inside your CardDeck Object. The reference you stored before in `deckBeforeShuffle` is still empty.

Comment: Im not sure how you mean. My deckBeforeShuffle is only empty after i call instance.shuffleDeck(); Is deckBeforeShuffle that is stored in my JUnit class going to change after I call instance.shuffleDeck() even if I dont use instance.getDeck() method after the shuffle method?

Comment: @Zok you have **one** object, with **two** references. One reference in your test `deckBeforeShuffle` and one in your `CardDeck`. Your shuffle function is removing the elements from this Object and add them to the `temp`. Then you overwrite the 2nd reference in in `CardDeck` with `temp`. Result is you `deckBeforeShuffle`is pointing to an empty List and instance to a new `shuffled` one.

Answer (score 0):

As described in this answer (and in many other sources around the Internet), there's [assertArrayEquals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457941/using-assertarrayequals-in-unit-tests#3458053), which does exactly that.