# JUnit test for reading csv file

Tags: java, file, junit, junit4

I have a method which reads a csv file line by line and put each record in a list. I want to test this method. What I have done is I created a list of expected records, then I create a csv file which contains the same records which i create in the list. I read this newly created csv file and put it in actual records list. Then I compare both the lists but it gives me an assertion error.

**java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[[Ljava.lang.String;@91b9b0]> but was <[[Ljava.lang.String;@1360c93]>**

Here is my code

```
String[] record = new String[] { "source", "name", "component", "10", "100", "10.5", "200", "15.5" }; 

MyReader reader = new MyReader();

@Test
public void readDataTest () throws FileNotFoundException
{
    List< String[] > expectedrecords = new ArrayList< String[] >();
    expectedrecords.add( record );

    List< String[] > actualrecords = new ArrayList< String[] >();
    generatetestCSV( dirPath + "\\Messages_Statistics.csv" );
    actualrecords = reader.readData( dirPath + "\\Messages_Statistics.csv" );

    Assert.assertEquals( expectedrecords, actualrecords );
}

private void generatetestCSV ( String fileName )
{
    try
    {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter( fileName );
        writer.append( "source" );
        writer.append( ',' );
        writer.append( "name" );
        writer.append( ',' );
        writer.append( "component" );
        writer.append( ',' );
        writer.append( "10" );
        writer.append( ',' );
        writer.append( "100" );
        writer.append( ',' );
        writer.append( "10.5" );
        writer.append( ',' );
        writer.append( "200" );
        writer.append( ',' );
        writer.append( "15.5" );
        writer.append( '\n' );
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

readData in MyReader Class is

```
  public List< String[] > readData ( String csvFile ) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    List< String[] > records = new ArrayList< String[] >();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( csvFile ) );
    String line = "";
    try
    {
        if ( csvFile != null )
        {
            if ( csvFile.contains( "Messages_Statistics" ) )
            {
                while ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null )
                {
                    String[] record = line.split( "," );
                    if ( records.size() < LIMIT )
                        records.add( record );
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
    {
        //logger.error( "Error in reading CSV file", e );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( br != null )
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return records;
}
```

Comment: You can not use `Assert.assertEquals` to compare `List<String[]>`.

Comment: What should I use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `Assert.assertEquals` to compare `List<String[]>`. This does not work:

```
List<String[]> expected = new ArrayList<>();
expected.add(new String[]{"foo", "bar"});
expected.add(new String[]{"baz", "qux"});

List<String[]> actual = new ArrayList<>();
actual.add(new String[]{"foo", "bar"});
actual.add(new String[]{"baz", "qux"});

Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual); // Fails!
```

You must do something like this:

```
List<String[]> expected = new ArrayList<>();
expected.add(new String[]{"foo", "bar"});
expected.add(new String[]{"baz", "qux"});

List<String[]> actual = new ArrayList<>();
actual.add(new String[]{"foo", "bar"});
actual.add(new String[]{"baz", "qux"});

assertEquals(expected.size(), actual.size());
for (int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < expected.get(i).length; j++) {
        Assert.assertEquals(expected.get(i)[j], actual.get(i)[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your for loops a bit

Comment: The outer loop is around the `List` (rows of the CSV), the inner is around the `String[]` (cells of the row). Each cell from `expected` is compared to the corresponding cell in `actual`.

Comment: Why not use `assertArrayEquals` - as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457941/using-assertarrayequals-in-unit-tests - in combination with `toArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.assertEquals( expectedrecords, actualrecords );
```

This is comparing list object instances which will not be same. You need to run over a loop and assert on individual entries of the list

Change your Assert check as below

```
 Assert.assertEquals(expectedrecords.size(),actualrecords.size());
    int count = 0;

    for(String[] lineData: expectedrecords)
    {
        String[] actualRecordData = actualrecords.get(count);
        count++;

        Assert.assertEquals( lineData.length,actualRecordData.length);

        for(int i = 0; i < lineData.length; i++)
        {
            Assert.assertEquals( lineData[i],actualRecordData[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that formats the lists into strings, and then compare the strings.  If they match, you are good.  If the do not, then the string diff is more readable than an exception talking about indexes in a list.  Especially if you run the test within IntelliJ or Eclipse, where they format the string to make the difference very clear.