# how to test if two arrays are equal in JUnit testing

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I have a class called MySet and this class does various operations to arrays, to explain, it adds, subtracts, multiplies, and divides arrays from/by other arrays. I want to test the array addition method to see if it runs correctly.

this the MySet class :

package lab;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MySet implements MyMath<MySet> {
int count = 0;
int[] firstArray = new int[count];

public MySet(int[] x) {

    int count = 0;
    Arrays.sort(x);
    for (int index = 0; index < x.length - 1; index++) {
        if (x[index] != x[index + 1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    firstArray = addToArray(x, count + 1);
  }
    public int[] addToArray(int[] x, int y) {
    int counter = 0;
    int[] changedArray = new int[y];
    for (int index = 0; index < x.length - 1; index++) {
        if (x[index] != x[index + 1]) {
            changedArray[counter] = x[index];
            counter++;
        }

    }
    changedArray[changedArray.length - 1] = x[x.length - 1];
    return changedArray;
  }

   public Boolean equals(MySet a) {
    if (a.firstArray.length != firstArray.length) {
        return false;
    }

    int test1 = firstArray.length - 1;
    int testValue = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < a.firstArray.length; index++) {
        if (firstArray[index] == a.firstArray[index]) {
            testValue++;
        }
    }
    if (test1 == testValue) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public MySet add(MySet o) {
    int[] addedSet = new int[firstArray.length + o.firstArray.length ];
    for (int index = 0; index < firstArray.length; index++) {
        addedSet[index] = firstArray[index];
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (int index = firstArray.length; index <= firstArray.length - 1 + 
    o.firstArray.length; index++) {
        addedSet[index] = o.firstArray[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(addedSet);
    addedSet = addToArray(addedSet, addedSet.length - 1);
    MySet finalSetAdd = new MySet(addedSet);
    return finalSetAdd;
    }

    @Override
    public MySet subtract(MySet o) {
    Arrays.sort(firstArray);
    Arrays.sort(o.firstArray);
    int count = 0;
    int finalCount = 0;
    int[] tester = addToArray(firstArray, firstArray.length - 1);
    int[] testing = addToArray(o.firstArray, o.firstArray.length - 1);

    for (int index = 0; index < testing.length; index++) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < tester.length; counter++) {
            if (tester[index] != testing[counter]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == tester.length) {
            finalCount++;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    int size = 0;
    int[] finalOne = new int[finalCount];
    for (int index = 0; index < o.firstArray.length; index++) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < firstArray.length; counter++) {
            if (testing[index] != tester[counter]) {
                finalOne[size] = testing[index];
                size++;
                finalOne = addToArray(finalOne, finalOne.length - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    MySet finalSetSub = new MySet(finalOne);
    return finalSetSub;

}

    @Override
    public MySet divide(MySet o) {
    Arrays.sort(firstArray);
    Arrays.sort(o.firstArray);
    int count = 0;
    int finalCount = 0;
    int[] tester = addToArray(firstArray, firstArray.length - 1);
    int[] testing = addToArray(o.firstArray, o.firstArray.length - 1);

    for (int index = 0; index < o.firstArray.length; index++) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < firstArray.length; counter++) {
            if (testing[index] == tester[counter]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == tester.length) {
            finalCount++;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    int size = 0;
    int[] finalOne = new int[finalCount];
    for (int index = 0; index < o.firstArray.length; index++) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < firstArray.length; counter++) {
            if (testing[index] == tester[counter]) {
                finalOne[size] = testing[index];
                size++;
                finalOne = addToArray(finalOne, finalOne.length - 1);

            }
        }
    }
    MySet finalSetSub = new MySet(finalOne);
    return finalSetSub;
    }

    @Override
    public MySet multiply(MySet o) {
    Arrays.sort(firstArray);
    Arrays.sort(o.firstArray);
    int count = 0;
    int finalCount = 0;
    int[] tester = addToArray(firstArray, firstArray.length - 1);
    int[] testing = addToArray(o.firstArray, o.firstArray.length - 1);

    for (int index = 0; index < o.firstArray.length; index++) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < firstArray.length; counter++) {
            if (testing[index] != tester[counter]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == firstArray.length - 1) {
            finalCount++;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    int counter1 = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int[] finalOne = new int[finalCount];
    for (int index = 0; index < o.firstArray.length; index++) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < firstArray.length; counter++) {
            if (testing[index] != tester[counter]) {
                counter1++;
            }
        }
        if (counter1 == firstArray.length - 1) {
            finalOne[size] = o.firstArray[index];
            size++;
        }

    }
    MySet finalSetSub = new MySet(finalOne);
    return finalSetSub;
    }

   public String toString(int x) {
    return "Value: " + firstArray[x];
   }

   }
```

and this is my test for the add method:

```
package test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import lab.MyMath;
import lab.MySet;

class MySetTest {
@Test
public void testMysetAdd() {
    int[] set1Arr = {1,2,6};
    MyMath<MySet> set1 = new MySet(set1Arr);
    int[] set2Arr = {4,5,6};
    MyMath<MySet> set2 = new MySet(set2Arr);
    int[] s = {1,2,4,5,6};
    MyMath<MySet> sum = new MySet(s);
    assertEquals(set1.add((MySet)set2).equals(sum), sum.equals(sum));
    }
}
```

After I run the test, the test fails in it says it says " expected <false> but was: <true> " so there is an error either in my add method in the MySet class where the two arrays could be not equal to their actual sum, the equals method in the MySet class where the method does not check correctly if the two arrays are equal, or in the test itself(I think the problem is in the test tbh). I just want to know what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457941/using-assertarrayequals-in-unit-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really checking the arrays but a custom object `MySet`. Unfortunately you haven't implemented `equals()`/`hashCode()`/`toString()` correctly.

1. Fix your `MySet.equals` signature. It must override `Object` method  `boolean equals(Object)` and not `Boolean equals(MySet a)`. You can apply `@Override` annotation to ensure this method is correctly overridden. Without this most of `JUnit` methods will fail.
2. Add a corresponding `int hashCode()` method.
3. Add a `String toString()` which will be used by assertion messages.
4. Change `assertEquals(set1.add((MySet)set2).equals(sum), sum.equals(sum));`
   should be written as: `assertEquals(sum, set1.add((MySet)set2));`.
5. You can try improving assertion message with `assertArrayEquals()` instead of `assertEquals()`. You can also try a more modern assertion library e.g. [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/).

Comment: don't you need to implement comparable interface for this too work?

Comment: JUnit `assertEquals()` uses regular `equals()` under the hood so `Comparable` is not required.

Comment: sorry for the late comment but for number 4, I thought we put the expected result , result. Also, for number 1 do you mean that the equals method should be an instance method?

Comment: @JavaProgramer It must use `Object` as a parameter, not `MySet`. It must override the method signature defined in `java.lang.Object`.