# JUnit test case for array used for concatenations

Tags: java, junit

this the concatenation of array code I tried writing the junit test case for it but its the giving the Syntax error. I am not sure whats the exact syntax.

```
public static String[] concatArray(String[] firstArry, String[] secArry) {
        if (null != firstArry && null == secArry) {
            return firstArry;
        } else if (null == firstArry && null != secArry) {
            return secArry;
        } else if( null != firstArry && null != secArry ){
            String[] concatArry = new String[firstArry.length + secArry.length];
            System.arraycopy(firstArry, 0, concatArry, 0, firstArry.length);
            System.arraycopy(secArry, 0, concatArry, firstArry.length, secArry.length);
            return concatArry;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
```

JUnit test case for it.

```
@Test
    public void testConcatArray() {
        String[] arr1 = {"nodename", "nodecategory"};
        String[] arr2 = {" test"," case"};

        Assert.assertEquals({"abc"}, StringUtils.concatArray(arr1, arr2));
    }
```

[image: Error]

Comment: try using assertArrayEquals() see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457941/using-assertarrayequals-in-unit-tests

Comment: i think it is because of `{"abc"}` this not valid in java

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know what is the actual type of the first param.

You need to use the following allong with a different assertion:

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[]{"abc"}, StringUtils.concatArray(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: its returning object because of that the junit testcase fails

Comment: Dont think it is even allowed without a type declaration first

Answer (score 0):

you can assert arrays using the `assertArrayEquals()` method.

see: [Using assertArrayEquals in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457941/using-assertarrayequals-in-unit-tests)

maybe you want to take a look at Java Stream API afaik it can also handle the concatenation of `null` arrays so you don't have to care about the null handling.
e.g. if you have an array `['abc']` and `null` the Stream concat would return `['abc']`.
( but maybe you need to filter before I am not 100% sure so: `yourStream.filter(array -> array != null)`)

take a look at this for better understanding of what I mean:

https://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-concat-streams-lists-sets-arrays-example